# UILabel text changing between two strings with each "touch up inside"

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I'm learning OBJ.C/Xcode/Cocoa here and have run into a question I can't seem to find an answer for.

I want the text in a UILabel to switch between two states (ON/OFF for example) each time the user clicks the same button.

I can get the label to switch to one state, but can't get it to switch "back" when the user clicks the button again.  I am assuming there is some logic required, or checking the status of the object once the button is clicked...

Does this require me to keep track of a bool or the "state" of the Label (or button)?
Would this require two methods to be associated to the button, or can it happen with just one?

Thanks for any guidance/pointing in the right direction/Code snips!!!!

~Steve

I got an answer, and it works:

```
- (IBAction)flip:(id)sender 
{
_flipButton.selected = !_flipButton.selected;
self.flipLabel.text = (_flipButton.selected) ? @"ON" : @"OFF";
}
```

Comment: Post your code, no it is just guess work.

Comment: The code for the method so far is as simple as it gets: (Sorry in advance I don't know how to post code snips..)                        - (IBAction)flip:(id)sender
{
   self.flipLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ON"];
  
}

Comment: @SteveMaietta Can you post the code in comments and add as edit to your post.

Comment: figured it out, thanks from a noob!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- (IBAction)flip:(id)sender {
[yourButton setSelected:!yourButton.selected]; 
self.flipLabel.text = (yourButton.selected) ? @"ON" : @"OFF"; 
}
```

This toggles the selected state of the button then checks its state to determine which string to pass to the text property of your label.

Comment: It may not actually be true, but question suggests that the label and button are separate objects.

Comment: THANK YOU Bamsworld, the code worked.  Something that works that I can study and figure out -thanks.   I had to change "sender" to my buttons name of course, and for some reason XCode required me to insert an undersocre before my buttons name before it recognized it as correct, but it did work.  Any thoughts on why xcode needed the underscore?     - (IBAction)flip:(id)sender {
    _flipButton.selected = !_flipButton.selected;
    self.flipLabel.text = (_flipButton.selected) ? @"ON" : @"OFF";
}

Comment: your welcome. Its because you are most likely accessing a backing ivar for a property of type UIButton named flipButton. You could alternatively wrote self.flipButton.selected instead of _flipButton.selected

Answer (score 1):

the easiest way (I think) is to store a `BOOL` with the state of the `UILabel` and (on each click of the button) negate the `BOOL` and set the appropriate text of the `Label`

Comment: So something like  IF bool ==1 flipLabel.text=@"ON", IF bool ==0 flipLabel.text= @"OFF"    Could this operate all within one method?

Comment: You could also write it that way: if(bool) flipLabel.text=@"ON"; else flipLabel.text=@"OFF"; and remember to do something like bool = !bool; before (or after, doesn't really matter) setting the text. There's no problem in putting it in one method.

Answer (score 0):

You could call this: `yourLabel.enabled = !yourLabel.enabled` on button click to change the enabled-state of your `UILabel`. Or what kind of state do you mean ?

Comment: I am not sure what state would be appropriate, or even if you had to check states at all.  But the idea of checking and changing states to direct the method to insert the appropriate text seemed appropriate!